# Addition of '#define xxx' after app release responded to user action

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, preprocessor

I have a paid app on the Apple app store, and I'm trying to make a free app with restricted features, to make it distinct from my paid app. I have used 'preprocessor macros' in Build Settings to discriminate these two app with LITE=1 key. Until this, it was all OK. Restricted features can be separated by use of '#ifdef LITE'

My problem is when the users buy in-app purchase for paid version features. It's easy if I can add '#define LITE' in the app when the users buy in app purchase. How can I get this?

Comment: wow, -1. because of sooooooo fundamental question?

Comment: There no such thing as a dumb question, but please make an effort in getting some basic knowledge of software development. In your case the difference between compile-time and run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. Preprocessor macros are PRE-processing: code removed, textual substitutions, #ifdefs, etc. are all done before the compiler even sees the code.

If you have removed code by surrounding it in an #ifdef block, it's gone. It's just not there.

You're going to have to use a different approach. You could add a variable somewhere, or a key in property list file. Then, you could use ordinary if() checks to check whether a feature should be enabled. When the in-app purchase completes, you can just flip the switch.

Comment: Thank you. It's not good behavior that uses #ifdef for restricted features if it would be unlocked later on, isn't it?